# Display an error message when upload wrong image type in input field using react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to display error message for "Please upload only Image Format".
Here is the code which I return to display an error message, when uploaded the pdf instead of uploading Image, The error message should display. I'm using react typescript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const [fileLogoError, setfileLogoError] = useState("");
const [selectedLogoFile, setselectedLogoFile] = useState<File>();

const handleLogoChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.target.files[0].type == "image/*") {
      setselectedLogoFile(event.target.files[0])
    } else {
      setfileLogoError("Please upload only Image Format");
    }
  }

return (
    // Uploading Image
    <input
         id="CT_SelectFile"
         onChange={handleLogoChange}
         name="file"
         ref={fileUpload}
         hidden
         multiple type="file"
         accept="image/*"
         />

    // Displaying the Image     
    {selectedLogoFile ?
     <>
                  <img src={imageUrl} height="45px" />
                  <Typography variant='subtitle1>
                    <span>{selectedLogoFile.name}</span>
                  </Typography>
                </>
                :
                <>
                  {fileLogoError ?
                    <Typography variant='subtitle1' >
                      {fileLogoError}
                    </Typography>
                    :
                    <>
                      <img src={previewFile} width="40px" height="40px" />
                      <Typography variant='subtitle1' >
                        Upload your Image
                      </Typography>
                    </>
                  }
                </>
        }
)
```

**Expected Output** : When upload only image type it should accept and display the image for preview, If it's not a image type it should display the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the condition to determine whether to show the image preview or error message. The condition `event.target.files[0].type == "image/*"` checks whether the type of file is exactly `image/*` but it never is. Consider you uploaded a `png` file, then the type would be `image/png` and not `image/*`. Instead of checking `image/*` directly, use a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
const handleLogoChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const {files} = event.target;
  if(!files) return;
  if (new RegExp("image/*").test(files[0].type)) {
    setselectedLogoFile(files[0]);
    setfileLogoError("");
  } else {
    setfileLogoError("Please upload only Image Format");
  }
};
```